# Fatal Error after migrating Wordpress site from one host to another

Tags: fatal-error, migration

I migrated my wordpress site from Bluehost to InMotion. It worked alright, I can now reach my wordpress site and most things work. However, when I click on "Customize" or "Header" in my Dashboard, I get following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'WP_Customize_Nav_Menu_Setting' not found in /home/arabst8/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-customize-nav-menus.php on line 490
```

Line 490, and following, in that file :

```
    public function filter_dynamic_setting_args( $setting_args, $setting_id ) {
    if ( preg_match( WP_Customize_Nav_Menu_Setting::ID_PATTERN, $setting_id ) ) {
        $setting_args = array(
            'type'      => WP_Customize_Nav_Menu_Setting::TYPE,
            'transport' => 'postMessage',
        );
    } elseif ( preg_match( WP_Customize_Nav_Menu_Item_Setting::ID_PATTERN, $setting_id ) ) {
        $setting_args = array(
            'type'      => WP_Customize_Nav_Menu_Item_Setting::TYPE,
            'transport' => 'postMessage',
        );
    }
    return $setting_args;
}
```

Why cant it find the class? Whats going on? Everything else seems to work.

Comment: Which version of Wordpress are you running?

Comment: Its Version 4.7.2

Comment: did that help??